# On Scope of Variables in .NET(c#)

Tags: c#, .net

Reference Code

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    string x;
    List sampleList = populateList();

    foreach(MyType myType in sampleList)
    {
        string x;   // why is this not allowed?
        doSomethingwithX(x);
    }
}
```

I recently started learning C# and today ran into issue with code similar to the above. VS2010 flagged the commented code with this message `a local variable named x cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to variable x which is already used in parent or current scope to denote something else`....

I dont get it...isnt that the whole essence of block statements and scoping...I know i can just change my variable names and go ahead.but i'd like to know WHY?

Comment: To prevent you from writing confusing code.

Comment: Readability? How easy would it be to read that method 6 months down the road?

Comment: I see but shdnt that be my headache?

Comment: To answer your question, How will you refer `x` which you declared top inside the loop?

Comment: Some languages allow it but C# does not. You can do it in Non-related scopes.

Comment: your first x has not been scoped out yet.  That's why you are receiving the error.

Comment: Our man Mr Jeff Atwood tells you exactly why the c# language is designed to stop you making life hard for yourself. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/falling-into-the-pit-of-success.html

If you want to take full responsibility for your own migraines, use C++.

Comment: Further, blocks are not scopes. Blocks encapsulate multi-line statements (for, foreach, while, switch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont get it...isnt that the whole essence of block statements and scoping...

No, not really. The intention of scoping isn't "to allow you to reuse names".

> I know i can just change my variable names and go ahead.but i'd like to know WHY?

It reduces the possibilities for confusing code, basically. There are various situations where C# prevents you from writing code which is confusing. Not as many as we might like, of course, but where there's no clear benefit from allowing something, and a clear benefit from *disallowing* it, it makes sense to disallow it.

Would you ever *want* to work with code that had the same local variable name in scope twice? Wouldn't you always prefer the original developer to use a different name? I would - so I'm glad the compiler enforces that.

Note that this doesn't prevent the same local variable name being used twice in the same method - they just can't be in the same scope. So this is valid:

```
public void Foo()
{
    {
        int x = 10;
        ...
    }

    {
        int x = 10;
        ...
    }
}
```

But this isn't:

```
public void Foo()
{
    {
        int x = 10;
        ...
    }

    int x = 10;
    ...
}
```

If the second example is confusing, you need to bear in mind that the scope of a local variable is the *block* in which it was declared - not from the declaration point onwards.

Comment: useful official reference text from ECMA-334 15.5.1, Local variable declarations: "The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration is the block in which the declaration occurs. It is an error to refer to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the local-variable-declarator of the local variable. Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to declare another local variable or constant with the same name."

Comment: simple and clear explanation...thanks

Answer (score 2):

Previously defined `x` is still in scope that's why compiler stops you from declaring other one.

You can verify this by limiting the scope of previous variable by wrapping it in curly braces -

```
  public void MyMethod()
  {
      {
        string x;
      }
      List sampleList = populateList();    
      foreach(MyType myType in sampleList)
      {
          string x;   // This will be fine.
          doSomethingwithX(x);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The x in the for loop is not visible outwith the loop, but the x you declared at the start of the method is visible within the for loop.

Outwith the loop you have one x but inside it there are two, both of which are being declared

Comment: yes i many have two x inside the loop but shd be able to differentiate them somehow....possibly with this

Comment: @oliverdejohnson If one were an instance field and one were a local then yes, you could use `this` to refer to the field and omit it to refer to the local.  Not coincidentally, such situations would be legal C# code.  With two locals of a different scope there *isn't* a way to refer to the outer local.

Comment: @oliverdejohnson If you have two variables that you want to differentiate then they should have different names. What if you wanted to use the x declared outwith the loop inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare    string x; again. .. it will have different meaning.  Since string x; is declared inside a method.  The scope of x will be available through out the method. . So please declare some other variable inside for each loop. ..

Or you can just x. Instead of declaring again. .